# Python - list of dicts into function that only accepts *dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a function that takes as input multiple dictionaries:

```
def multi_dicts(*dicts):
```

I have a variable that is a list of multiple dictionaries:

```
list_of_dicts=[{'2014-09': 209.0, '2014-08': 243.0},{'2014-09': 40.0, '2014-08': 300.0},{'2014-09': 100.0, '2014-08': 2.0}]
```

Is there a way to use those dictionaries inside the list_of_dicts as arguments of `multi_dicts(*dicts)`, assuming that we do not know how many dictionaries will be inside list_of_dicts (it varies a lot)?

In a gross manner, would look like this:

```
multi_dicts(*dictionaries_found_inside_list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: Isn't it just `multi_dicts(*list_of_dicts)`?..

Comment: Isn't the answer in the question?

Comment: Everyday Python impresses me on how intuitive it can be. I didn't know I could use it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
multi_dicts(*list_of_dicts)
```

Putting an asterisk in front of a list argument will unpack it.

So:

```
def foo(*bars):
    for bar in bars:
        print(bar)

list_of_things = ['one', 'two', 'three']

foo(*list_of_things)
```

Will print:

```
one
two
three
```

This works just as well if the list contains dictionaries.